# is it possible to authenticate telnet automatically?

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

When using [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html) I noticed some interesting variables:

```
AUTHENTICATION = chr(37) # Authenticate
XAUTH = chr(41) # XAUTH
PRAGMA_LOGON = chr(138) # TELOPT PRAGMA LOGON
SSPI_LOGON = chr(139) # TELOPT SSPI LOGON
```

Also, [this page](http://pcmicro.com/netfoss/telnet.html) lists some RFCs which describe `AUTHENTICATION` option in detail.

If I understand correctly, if a telnet server supports authentication I should be receiving `IAC DO AUTHENTICATION` when connecting to it. However, when trying to connect to *telnetd* on a Linux machine I do not receive this option and so I can't send `IAC WILL AUTHENTICATION`.

Is my understandng correct? Is there a way I can ask the server to perform authentication? Is it even possible to authenticate telnet session automatically? (without listening to "Login:", "Username:", "Password:" and similar prompts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are understanding [RFC 1416](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1416.txt) correctly. The server should send `DO` first, if it supports authentication. You can try sending `WILL` anyway but that'll be against the spec and probably won't work anyway.

By Linux telnetd, you probably mean the netkit telnetd. And as far as I can see on its manpage:

> *-a authmode*  This option may be used for specifying what mode should be used for
>                   authentication.  Note that this option is only useful if telnetd has
>                    been compiled with support for authentication, **which is not available
>                    in the current version**. [...]

So I'd simply say it can't do that. I'm using the OpenBSD telnetd (`telnet-bsd` package in Gentoo); it seems to have some auth bits but I wasn't able to get it to work at all. I suspect it only supports Kerberos-based auth.

Looking at the authentication types list in [RFC 2941](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2941.txt), it seems that most authentication types were never even specified. Looking at those which are, DSS/DSA is mostly interesting (it is used in SSH as well) but I guess it will be really hard to find a compliant server *and* client. Sadly, it seems that there were no proposals for simple (plaintext) authentications there.

So, to sum up: yes, it *would* be possible if someone implemented it. But since telnet is practically dead, I doubt you'll find server implementations for that. And even if you did, you'd have to write the client-side yourself which won't be that easy with the supported schemes. So I doubt it's worth the effort.

Comment: Ah, I missed that "not available" bit... :) I figured this was the case, but it is nice to get a confirmation. Thank you!